# center output with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf

I am using JSpdf library, right here --> http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/

To generate PDF based off of static page that user is on, this works just fine the only problem is, the PDF generates aligned to the left (it's not like this on the static page itself, just the generates pdf)

So, how could I have the outcome of generated PDF to be 'centered' the same as the static page?

**Relevant JS is below:**

```
texts = {
      item1: 'Item Box 1 Content <strong>html</strong> right here! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
      item2: 'Now its Item Box 2 <strong>html</strong> content here ! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
      item3: 'This is the example <strong>html</strong> of Item box 4! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
      item4: 'Item box number 5 <strong>html</strong> content is here! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
    }
    $("#container").css('background', '#fff')

     $('.download-pdf').click(function() {

      notChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").parent();
      notChecked.hide();
      yesChecked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").parent();

      $.each(yesChecked, function( index, el ) {
        $(el).show().html(texts[$(el).attr('id')]);
      });

     var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

      pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('records'), function() {

          setTimeout(function(){
           location.reload();
           },3000);
      }); 

      var file = 'test';
      if (typeof doc !== 'undefined') {
          doc.save(file + '.pdf');
      } else if (typeof pdf !== 'undefined') {
          setTimeout(function() {
              pdf.save(file + '.pdf');
              // $("#item4").hide();

          }, 2000);
      } else {
          alert('Error 0xE001BADF');
      }

  });
```

thanks everyone, for your *candor*.